# Login page displayed for a second

Tags: android, facebook-login

My Android App start with a Facebook Login page and if the user is logged jet skip to the home page.

The problem is that if the user is logged jet the home page will be displayed for a second.

Here is my starter code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private AccessTokenTracker mAccessTokenTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    final Context context=this;

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        mAccessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                mAccessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
                if(currentAccessToken == null) {
                    Log.i("LOGIN","ALL PERMISSION DELETED, SKIP TO THE LOGIN");
                }
                else {
                    //CHECK PERMISSION ONE BY ONE
                    String current_permission =currentAccessToken.getPermissions().toString();
                    if (current_permission.contains("user_photos") && current_permission.contains("user_post") && current_permission.contains("public_profile")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOU ARE LOGGED IN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent); //USER IS LOGGED IN AND HAVE ALL PERMISSION SO GO TO THE HOME PAGE
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync();
    }
    else {
        Log.i("LOGIN","NEED TO LOG IN");
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ......
    //GO TO THE LOGIN PAGE
```

How can i avoid that and what is THE BEST PRACTICE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you user is logged in just make sure you don't call setContentView() after startActivity() has been called. That way you're not inflating your layout unless the user is not logged in.

You can do this in many ways including just returning from the method after startActivity() is called.